# We will throw a party "on the day when" Space-X send my friends to the other planets. - a high level of certainty?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

**Example 1**

> Famine will strike human-beings **when** the war breaks out among nations.

**Example 2**

> Famine will strike human-beings **if** the war breaks out among nations.

"when" conveys a high level of certainty as opposed to "if."

However, how about expressions such as "on the day when" and "in the year when"?

**Example 3**

> Famine will strike human-beings **in the year when** the war breaks out among nations.

**Example 4**

> We will throw a party **on the day when** Space-X sends my friends to the other planets.

When they are used, do they usually express a high level of certainty?

Comment: NB We say _when war breaks out_ to mean 'a state of armed conflict'. _The war_ means a particular conflict, e.g. 'The First World War'.

Comment: We don't hyphenate 'human beings'.

Answer (score 1):

> We will throw a party for you when pigs fly.

The "high level of certainty" is that you will have a party when the condition is met.  The condition itself may be uncertain, or in the case of sarcasm, certain not to happen.

> We will let you use the car when you pass your driver's test.

You might fail that test, and in fact you might have failed it several times already. That's not the issue.  The high level of certainty is that you will be given access to the car if the condition is met.

When the future action  is not under the control of the speaker (that is, *you* will  vs we will), there may be a greater sense that the speaker feels the condition itself is likely.

> You will regret your life of bank robbery when you get caught.

You might be a very resourceful and elusive bank robber but the speaker believes there's a good chance you will live to regret your life of bank robbery.

Supplemental phrases, including but not limited to time-phrases, *when used idiomatically and sensibly*, can suggest the speaker feels a greater sense of likelihood that the condition itself will be met.

> You will regret your life of crime when you get caught pulling Thursday's heist.

Answer (score 0):

Your example 1 suggests ***a direct cause-and-effect relationship between the war and famine***

Your example 2 suggests ***famine is a possibility or potential outcome if a war breaks out***(but the sentence lacks definiteness)

Comment: example 2 clearly says that famine will definitely happen IF war breaks out. The only uncertainty is whether or not war will break out. If it does then famine is certain. "X will if Y"  means X is a certainty if Y happens.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between "if" and "when" in 1 and 2 is in the certainty of the second event. "when" means that the second event will happen at some point in the future (rather than might). For "in the year when", etc., the second event will definitely happen and the first will happen in the same year as it. The level of certainty of the second event is unaffected by the qualifying "in the year". Does this help?

Comment: "On the day when Space-X sends my friends to the other planets, we will throw a party." 
"In the year when the war breaks out among nations, famine will strike human-beings."
Both convey a high level of certainty from the speaker, right?

Comment: Yes, it's the "when" that conveys the certainty, as opposed to "if" in the other original example. "On the day" narrows down when the party (for example) will happen, it doesn't make it more certain. Certainty is given by the words "when" and "will".

Comment: Sometimes we say 'if and when' to cover both ends.